# Java Spring how to fill configuration automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i try to authwire configuration using spring
All complies fine and the server is running , but the configurator never triggered
//Main class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MainApplication.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(Collections
                .singletonMap("server.port", "8083"));
        app.run(args);

    }
}
```

// **this class i like the Map<String, CarsInfo> carsInfos map** will be filled automatically

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AppManager {

    private final Map<String, CarsInfo> carsInfos;

    @Autowired
    public AppManager(Map<String, CarsInfo> carsInfos) {
        this.carsInfos = carsInfos;

    }
}


public class CarsInfo {
    private String id;
    private  String data;

    public CarsInfo(String id,String data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class Config1 {


    @Bean ("DATA_FILLER")
    public String getData() {
        return "Car Test";
    }

    @Bean(IDs.CAR_ID)
    public CarsInfo carInfo(@Qualifier("DATA_FILLER") String data) {
        return new CarsInfo(IDs.CAR_ID,data);
    }
}


@Configuration
public class Config2 {
    @Bean("DATA_FILLER")
    public String getData() {
        return "Tractor Test";
    }

    @Bean(IDs.TRACTOR_ID)
    public CarsInfo tractorInfo(@Qualifier("DATA_FILLER") String data) {
        return new CarsInfo(IDs.CAR_ID,data);
    }
}

public class IDs {

public static final String CAR_ID = "car_id";
public static final String TRACTOR_ID = "tractor_id";

}
```

Comment: you might try something like this:

    @Autowired
    public AppManager(List<CarsInfo> carsInfos) {
 list.forEach(cars -> carsInfos.put(cars.getId(), cars)))
    }

Comment: And what doesn't work according to you? ONe thing I see that is "wrong" is that the `getData` overrides the other, so there is only 1 `DATA_FILLER` basically the last one.

Comment: @M.Deinum tnx yes this was a problem , when fixed all worked . 
but i dont understand this in spring ...
is it "Spring" role ? i can't find any information that explain this concept in spring.
how does spring knows to keep all the objects in hash map ?

Comment: It doesn't keep stuff in a `HashMap`, the `Map<String, Object>` is a special injection type which will result in all beans gettig injected with the name (and corresponding type), same with a typed collection. This is also explained in the reference guide (for collections, arrays and maps).